# Function Objection Notation?

Tags: javascript, function, object, notation

I was wondering whether there is any performance / advantage of writing javascript in this format ?

```
var myFuncs = {
  var firstFun = function() {
    // do something
  },

  var secondFunc = function() {
    // do something
  },

  var thirdFunc = function() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

So they can be called like

```
myFuncs.firstFun();
```

I'm trying to understand how this is more advantageous [other than code readability] ?

Comment: Advantage over what, making them global?

Comment: that is `syntactically incorrect`

Comment: Well making them like `myFuncs.firstFun();` or just `firstFun()`

Comment: Your code will never run, so it will be very fast.

Comment: I'm trying to establish the advantage/disadvantage of putting functions within `var myFuncs = {}` as opposed to just using `firstFun()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Function vs Object declaration

You can't use that particular syntax, the correct form is:

```
var myFuncs = {
  firstFn: function () {},
  secondFn: function () {},
  ...
};
```

The advantage to writing functions within an object has to do with namespacing and context. If you wrote:

```
var firstFn = function () {};
-or-
function firstFn() {}
```

the function would be defined at `window.firstFn`. Adding the functions on `myFuncs` makes the functions accessible at `window.myFuncs.firstFn`. If you want your JavaScript to work with other scripts you wouldn't want to have your `foo` function conflict with someone elses `foo` function:

```
<script src="a.js">
function foo() {...}
</script>

<script src="b.js">
function foo() {...} //this script would overwrite the foo function in a.js
</script>

<script src="c.js">
var bar = { //this script would be accessed at bar.foo()
  foo: function () {..}
}
</script>
```

The calling context (`this`) of the function will also be different:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this); //window
}
var bar = {
  foo: function () {
    console.log(this); //bar object
  }
}
```

---

### Closure Syntax

What you may be getting confused with is the syntax for declaring functions within a closure:

```
(function () {
  var foo = function () {...};
  foo();
}());
```

In this case the closure is used to prevent the function from polluting the global scope (`window.foo` will not be set). This allows multiple scripts to use the same function names without worrying about being overridden.

---

### OOP Syntax

The object syntax is often used to define the prototype for a JavaScript "constructor". In JS all functions can be called as a constructor simply by using the `new` keyword when the function is called:

```
function foo() {...}
var f = new foo(); //don't do it this way
```

For readability/maintainability/consistency you should always name your constructor using PascalCase:

```
function Foo() {...} //tells other developers this is a constructor
function bar() {...} //tells other developers this is a function
var f = new Foo();
var b = bar();
```

Without getting too lost in the details of how prototype works, you can assign methods to be shared across every instantiated object of a function by assigning an object to the function's `prototype` property:

```
function Foo() {...}
Foo.prototype = { //note the use of the object declaration for the functions
  bar: function () {...},
  baz: function () {...},
  ...
};
var f = new Foo();
f.bar(); //calls the bar function that was defined in the prototype
```

Comment: thanks. so in your opinion it is better "practice" to write within objects for my web application ? i.e. is better in the sense that it allows you to specifically declare myFuncs.firstFun(); which restricts the global scope - while probably making it easier to read ? i.e. account.settings(); etc ?

Comment: Start with writing your functions within a closure. If they're needed outside the closure, set them explicitly on the global object (i.e. `window.foo = foo`). Within the closure, if you have a need of Object Oriented JavaScript, declare some constructors and set the functions on the `prototype`.

Comment: just one last question. would this mean that the best practice would also be to place [i.e. using jQuery] - all your plugins in the same format ? i.e. `var MyCompany = MyCompany || {}; MyCompany.Plugins = {};` and then use like `MyCompany.Plugins.Blah()` and `MyCompany.Plugins.Ha()` etc ?

Comment: jQuery plugins and widgets are typcially named `jQuery.plugin.[version].js` and would be expected to override `$.fn.plugin` and/or `$.plugin`. This naming convention makes it easy to know when plugins are going to conflict, you wouldn't include multiple `jQuery.foo.js` files, even if they did different things. If you're making a stand-alone lib for your company you might make `lib.js` and then `lib.foo.js` and then `lib.bar.js`, or you could simply use `lib.js` to include `lib.foo` and `lib.bar` but the assumption from the name would be that the script overrides `window.lib`.

Comment: but what if I want to call functions within the restricted scope so I can figure out what pages use what functions clearly ? that is like `MyCompany.Account.Settings = function() { //some stuff; MyCompany.Plugins.Ha(); }; ` ?

Comment: @Andy, read up on how closures work in JS and don't scope things quite as deeply. Only expose the necessary objects for the api. You're overcomlicating things.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is for advantages between declaring all of your functions globally, vs putting them all into an object.  There is no performance difference.  The main reason why people generally suggest adding them all into an object is to not clutter up the global space.

Think about it this way.  If you create a global function named `init` in a javascript library, and make it global.  Then if someone else does the same, it will overwrite your `init`. But, if you put it in an object named `someJSLibrary`, the odds of some other code overwriting your functions are much less.

Comment: exactly :) cool thanks. so writing within objects is better in the sense that it allows you to specifically declare `myFuncs.firstFun();` which restricts the global scope - while probably making it easier to read ? i.e. `account.settings();` etc ?